What is Hawking radiation? How to derive it by background field method?
I'm an intro-QFT student and I don't know much GR.
I want to understand. What is Hawking radiation? Seems it's usually not done by background field method?
I'm confused what does the presence of the horizon does?
I'm now guessing it's due to some accelerating effects and I'm trying to look at some explanations. But how to derive all those from background field method and some corrections where you still study QFT under the presence of a curved spacetime plus sources
$\textbf{Update}$
Okay now I searched more the literature. What I am referring is not the generic QFT in the presence of horizon effect, but to calculate it in the framework of EFT.
Since this is a paper of 2 months ago, and they say they are still trying to repeat Hawking radiation within the EFT framework. So I think it's hard to answer
C. Cheung, et al, Gravitational Scattering and Beyond from Extreme Mass Ratio Effective Field Theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.14770


I mean, technically quantum field theory in curved spacetimes is a particular case of the background field theory, but this particular background field is fairly complicated, since it determines causality and the symmetries of spacetime

@NíckolasAlves Yes. Then I want to know is this a zero-loop correction? Or people just say this is a basic feature with the presence of event horizon?
I'm aware this fact in the question and I think I am getting downvote because they don't allow non-technical questions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@wethkhsk In a sense, it is a basic feature of the event horizon. The natural vacuum state in the presence of an event horizon is thermal. The downvotes are probably because the question lacks clarity on what exactly you are asking

This question is similar to: How is Hawking radiation formally derived?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NíckolasAlves See my update description. I don't mean Hawking's original derivation. But what is Hawking radiation, if it's robust then it should be able to derive similar effects other way like the paper above suggest

@wethkhsk Hawking radiation is a robust prediction in the sense it can be computed in many different ways, although there are open questions. The authors of the paper you mentioned seem to be speculating on a possible new derivation, but I don't know (and they don't seem to know either) whether this derivation is achievable. Maybe it can be formalized into a new derivation, but that seems to be ongoing research from what they write

@NíckolasAlves Yes. And if they couldn't, in the framework of EFT fluctuations around a curve metric, then it will be a big problem. Which I bet there is a chance since a preliminary look makes me believe the semiclassical analysis IS NOT a good framework (quantum fields on a curved spacetime) where quantum fields are distributions on the curve spacetime satisfying the microlocal relations, formulating local and covariantly.
And my whole point asking about this question is to look for any intuition

@wethkhsk I haven't read their paper in detail, but at this point I'm not really concerned with whether their calculation works or not. QFTCS is a robust framework both physically and mathematically, at least as far its assumptions (reasonable well-defined classical background) are respected. In any case, I suggest you rephrase your question to be more directed at what you are actually interested

@NíckolasAlves When you say it's mathematically robust. You are aware of Witten's and Wald's work on it? The algebraic formulation. And I disagree the robustness. It should not stand, even as an approximation to real low-energy QG

@wethkhsk Yes, I am talking about the algebraic approach. Not only Wald and Witten, but also Fredenhagen's group, etc. Notice that at low curvatures, Hawking radiation is not yet about QG, only about quantum fields on an evolving spacetime. Even in a QG context, there seems to be very little room for the calculations to be modified for large black holes
